# How to pass package name to a antlr4 grammar using gradle antlr plugin without using @header

Tags: antlr4, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to set up Antlr task in gradle to generate sources in a folder matching the package name.

I have tried to add the package in the @header of the grammar however this does not generate the package folder tree the same way as i.e. IntelliJ Antlr plugin.
I have alo tried to use the CLI arguments by passing the package to the attibutes as per the sample below.

```
generateGrammarSource {
    maxHeapSize = "64m"
    arguments += ["-package my.package.name", "-visitor"]
}
```

However what I'm getting is

> Task :generateGrammarSource FAILED
>       error(2):  unknown command-line option -package my.package.name

When I put `-package` and `my.package.name` into separate entries (`["-package", "my.package.name", "-visitor"]`) the code generation runs but neither the package is added to the code nor the folders are created. It seems like it got ignored

I use Antlr version 4.7.2, and gradle bundled with intellij 191.

Is there a gradle-specific way of setting the output location of the antlr plugin based on the package name?

Comment: `-package` should work. What happens if you do: `arguments += ["-package", "my.package.name", "-visitor"]`?

Comment: @BartKiers, when I put `-package` and `my.package.name` into separate entries  the code generation runs but neither the package is added to the code nor the folders are created. It seems like it got ignored...

Comment: OK, then I'm out of ideas (I've never used used Gradle with ANTLR together). I added that extra piece of info to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at an old project, I used the following configuration with wrapper at `4.10.2` and whatever antlr plugin version was bundled with that:

```
generateGrammarSource {
    outputDirectory = file("$outputDirectory/org/mellowd/compiler")
    arguments += ['-package', 'org.mellowd.compiler']
    arguments += ['-visitor']
    arguments += ['-no-listener']

    inputs.files(source.files)
}
```

The `inputs.files(source.files)` was required at the time because the task was incorrectly being considered up to date despite the grammar changing, not sure if that part is still necessary.

It is your responsibility to make sure the path within the output directory matches that of the package specified.

Comment: This acctually worked. It seems the solution was to put `arguments += ['-package', 'org.mellowd.compiler']` as a separete assigment, not sure why it matters... as per file forlder structure I simply used same variable for the package name and the folders, obviously replacing '.' with '/'.

Answer (score 0):

For those using the **Gradle Kotlin DSL**, note that you would have to replace the Groovy syntax

```
    arguments += ['-package', 'org.mellowd.compiler']
```

from @SpencerPark's answer by

```
    arguments = arguments + listOf("-package", "org.mellowd.compiler")
```

The `inputs.files(...)` directive doesn't seem to be necessary, and the `outputDirectory` doesn't have to be set explicitly if you put your grammar file in the folder corresponding to the output package (src/main/antlr/org/mellowd/compiler). So,

```
    generateGrammarSource {
        arguments = arguments + listOf("-package", "org.mellowd.compiler")
        arguments = arguments + listOf("-visitor")
        arguments = arguments + listOf("-no-listener")
    }
```

should suffice.